# How do I make an object instantly drop to the ground (skipping the fall animation) in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Now, I have an object wherein I only know the x and z location. If I place it at a very high y coordinate, I would get an animation of it falling down towards the ground. I want to skip this and instantly make it be on the ground. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the object at an arbitrary Y-position well above the ground, then cast a ray down to the ground and move the object to the hit position.

Pseudo-code:

```
transform.position.y = 200f;
if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, out var hit)) {
    transform.position = hit.point;
}
```

Comment: Consider the pivot position of the cube for this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Raycast](https://docs.unity3d.com/550/Documentation/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) or [Boxcast](https://docs.unity3d.com/550/Documentation/ScriptReference/Physics.BoxCast.html) to determine the distance from the bottom of your object to the next collider below it. Then just subtract this distance from the objects transform.position.y.